# Determine image in memory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, identification, python-magic, imghdr

I want to determine if a buffer I have (downloaded it) is an image file, without saving it to the disk. I looked it up and found out that:

1. imghdr can do it only for files.
2. python-magic can give me the file type, but than I need to map it to image types.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html), you can identify the file type with `imghdr` via a byte stream (which you should be able to get from your buffer)

```
import imghdr
imghdr.what('', byte_stream)
```

If you supply the second parameter the filename will be ignored.